# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export when trying to use @babel/register

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering

When trying to run node with Babel and react, @babel/register does not work

I looked at similar issues on SO, reinstalled node 10.15.1, upgraded to latest version 11.9.

Here are the relevant dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "7.0.0",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "7.0.1",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
}
```

Trying to execute what this tutorial says about running SSR with react.
my index.js looks like this:

```
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//,    
],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    'dynamic-import-node',

  ]
});

require('./server');
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from '../src/App'


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const router = express.Router()

const serverRenderer = (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return res.status(500).send('An error occurred')
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
      )
    )
  })
}
router.use('^/$', serverRenderer)

router.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'), { maxAge: '30d' })
)
// tell the app to use the above rules
app.use(router)


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

When running from the CLI like this:

```
npm run build
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js
```

I consistently get this error:

```
/Users/myfolder/workspace/webapp/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
    at Module._compile (/Users/myfolder/workspace/webapp/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/myfolder/workspace/webapp/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
```

UPDATE: I am able to run the node server successfully, if I cd into the server folder.
My folder structure is:
myapp/src/server/index.js

This works - altho not ideal.

cd myapp/src/server 
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js

I don't get the above error. I am using webpack to build the app, makes me think this has something to do with my webpack config.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by adding the root dir for the babel. 'root' is a config loading option for babel that specifies the conceptual root folder for the current babel project. My cwd was src. The src/server/index.js now looks like this.

```
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//], 
root:"./server",   
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    'dynamic-import-node',

  ]
});

require('./server');
```

Comment: This helped me as I realized I was trying to import a file from outside the root-folder i.e: `import something from '../../somefile.js'` which babel won't touch